# Консоль зависает при выполнении

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[20]="0000011100111100011";
    int n = strlen(str);
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

суть задания: Дана строка, состоящая из групп нулей и единиц. Подсчитать количество символов в самой длинной группе.

Comment: Используйте цэ++ методы, раз эта метка стоит

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ключевая ошибка здесь:

```
while (str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
    count++;
}
```

В этом цикле вы не изменяете `i`, из-за чего программа входит в бесконечный цикл.

Вы можете сделать это так (минимальные изменения в вашем коде):

```
int main(){
    char str[20]="0000011100111100011";
    int n = strlen(str);
    int count = 1; // начальную длину установим в 1
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
            count++;
            ++i; // Вот здесь мы увеличим i
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
        count = 1; // "Обнулим" длину для новой последовательности
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Или можно так (более оптимально):

```
int main(){
    string str = "0000011100111100011";
    int n = str.length();
    int i = -1;
    int maximum = 1;
    while(++i < n){
        int counter = 1;
        while (str[i] == str[++i])
            ++counter;
        if (counter > maximum)
            maximum = counter;
    }
    cout << maximum;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вам надо `while` поменять на `if`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[20]="0000011100111100011";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int n = str[0];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (n != str[i]){
            if (count > max) max = count;
            count = 0;
            n = str[i];
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

пример с использованием цикла `while`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[20]="0000011100111100011";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int n = str[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        while (n == str[i]) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
        count = 0;
        n = str[i];
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ответ 4, а на сколько я понял, должен быть 5

Comment: А почему while не подходит? Ну, хотелось бы узнать, что не так с ним.

Comment: @mirrormirrormirror у вас во вложенном while i не изменяется, и поэтому постоянно сравниваются одинаковые буквы

Comment: @timur здесь промлемма в самом алгоритме

Comment: А можно же как-то сделать, чтобы i все же менялась в while?